# load equally named excel files located in subfolders into R and bind them

Tags: r, loops, subdirectory

I am searching for a solution to load several equally named Excel files located in several subfolders into R.

When those excel files were located in the same folder and all contain "MZB" as part of their name, I could easily apply a loop such as:

```
setwd('C:\Users\RandomGuy\Workspace\')
dir()

combination <- dir()[grepl('MZB', dir())]
# loop
for (i1 in 1:length(combination)) print(readxl::excel_sheets(combination[[i1]])); rm(i1)
# checking of 
comb <- list()
for (i1 in 1:length(combination)) {
  comb[[i1]] <- readxl::read_xlsx(combination[[i1]], sheet='')
  print(names(comb[[i1]])) }; rm(i1)
comb <- do.call('rbind', comb)
```

Now, I have the issue, that those excel files are not located in the same folder but instead in several subfolders.
Is there are way to access those and merge equally named Excel files (or at least one sheet at a time) into R?

Comment: ```list.files()``` might be a relevant functino, take a look at the ```recursive``` argument. When set to ```TRUE``` files in subfolders are also included.

Answer (score 1):

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "listen.xlsx", path = "C:/...", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
lst_of_frames <- lapply(files, readxl::read_excel, sheet='')


oneframe <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", lst_of_frames)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).